# ReactJS Authenticated Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router-dom

I have used react-router-dom for Navigation..but My Problem is without authentication also Dashboard Screen is being visible for mili seconds.

**App.js**

```
 <Route index path="/" element={<ProtectedRoute><Dashboard /></ProtectedRoute>} />
 <Route path="/Login" element={<Login />} />
```

**ProtectedRoute**

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { user } = useMyContext();
  if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to="/Login" />;
  }
  return children;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

**Login.js**

onClick..

```
 await login(data.get('email'), data.get('password'));
            navigate('/', { replace: true })
```

Context.js

```
function login(email, password) {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password) 
}
function logOut() {
    return signOut(auth);
}
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentuser) => {
        setUser(currentuser);
    });
    return () => {
        unsubscribe();
    }
}, [])
```

How can I protect my protected screen from unauthorized access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your `ProtectedRoute` component doesn't wait for the authentication status to be confirmed. In other words, the default `user` state masks one of either the authenticated or unauthenticated status.

It should conditionally render a loading indicator while `onAuthStateChanged` is making the first call to determine the user's authentication status. For the initial `user` state value use a value that is neither a defined user object in the case of an authenticated user or `null` in the case of an unauthenticated user. `undefined` is a good initial value.

Example:

Context

```
const [user, setUser] = React.useState(); // initially undefined

function login(email, password) {
  return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
}

function logOut() {
  return signOut(auth);
}

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentuser) => {
    setUser(currentuser);
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

ProtectedRoute

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { user } = useMyContext();

  if (user === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return user ? children : <Navigate to="/Login" replace />;
};
```