# Log-in page not redirecting to user dashboard after firebase log-in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, react-router

I'm trying to make protected routes for my website using React and firebase. It works fine when users log-in with email but when users log-in with firebase, the page refreshes before it has time to update verification status so it reloads to the log-in page again but when I manually refresh, it goes to the protected page. I'm not sure how to fix so that it will work for firebase log-in as well.

Actions.js:

```
import * as types from "./actionTypes";
import { auth, googleAuthProvider, facebookAuthProvider } from '../Firebase';

const registerStart = () => ({
    type: types.REGISTER_START,
});

const registerSuccess = (user) => ({
    type: types.REGISTER_SUCCESS,
    payload: user,
});

const registerFail = (error) => ({
    type: types.REGISTER_FAIL,
    payload: error,
});

const loginStart = () => ({
    type: types.LOGIN_START,
});

const loginSuccess = (user) => ({
    type: types.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    payload: user,
});

const loginFail = (error) => ({
    type: types.LOGIN_FAIL,
    payload: error,
});

const logoutStart = () => ({
    type: types.LOGOUT_START,
});

const logoutSuccess = (user) => ({
    type: types.LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
});

const logoutFail = (error) => ({
    type: types.LOGOUT_FAIL,
    payload: error,
});

export const setUser = (user) => ({
    type: types.SET_USER,
    payload: user,
})

const googleSignInStart = () => ({
    type: types.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_START,
});

const googleSignInSuccess = (user) => ({
    type: types.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS,
});

const googleSignInFail = (error) => ({
    type: types.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_FAIL,
    payload: error,
});

const fbSignInStart = () => ({
    type: types.FACEBOOK_SIGN_IN_START,
});

const fbSignInSuccess = (user) => ({
    type: types.FACEBOOK_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS,
});

const fbSignInFail = (error) => ({
    type: types.FACEBOOK_SIGN_IN_FAIL,
    payload: error,
});

export const registerInitiate = (email, password, displayName) => {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(registerStart());
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(({user}) => {
            user.updateProfile({
                displayName
            })
            dispatch(registerSuccess(user));
        }).catch((error) => dispatch(registerFail(error.message)))
    }
};

export const loginInitiate = (email, password) => {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(loginStart());
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(({user}) => {
            dispatch(loginSuccess(user));
        }).catch((error) => dispatch(loginFail(error.message)))
    }
};

export const logoutInitiate = () => {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(logoutStart());
        auth.signOut().then((resp) => 
            dispatch(logoutSuccess())
        ).catch((error) => dispatch(logoutFail(error.message)));
    }
};

export const googleSignInInitiate = () => {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(googleSignInStart());
        auth.signInWithPopup(googleAuthProvider).then(({user}) => {
            dispatch(googleSignInSuccess(user));
        }).catch((error) => dispatch(googleSignInFail(error.message)));
    }
};

export const fbSignInInitiate = () => {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(fbSignInStart());
        auth.signInWithPopup(facebookAuthProvider.addScope("user_birthday, email")).then(({user}) => {
            dispatch(fbSignInSuccess(user));
        }).catch((error) => dispatch(fbSignInFail(error.message)));
    }
};
```

actionTypes.js:

```
export const REGISTER_START = "REGISTER_START";
export const REGISTER_SUCCESS = "REGISTER_SUCCESS";
export const REGISTER_FAIL = "REGISTER_FAIL";

export const LOGIN_START = "LOGIN_START";
export const LOGIN_SUCCESS = "LOGIN_SUCCESS";
export const LOGIN_FAIL = "LOGIN_FAIL";

export const LOGOUT_START = "LOGOUT_START";
export const LOGOUT_SUCCESS = "LOGOUT_SUCCESS";
export const LOGOUT_FAIL = "LOGOUT_FAIL";

export const SET_USER = "SET_USER";

export const GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_START = "GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_START";
export const GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS = "GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS";
export const GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_FAIL = "GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_FAIL";

export const FACEBOOK_SIGN_IN_START = "FACEBOOK_SIGN_IN_START";
export const FACEBOOK_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS = "FACEBOOK_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS";
export const FACEBOOK_SIGN_IN_FAIL = "FACEBOOK_SIGN_IN_FAIL";
```

reducer.js:

```
const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    currentUser: null,
    error: null,
}

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.REGISTER_START:
        case types.LOGIN_START:
        case types.LOGOUT_START:
        case types.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_START:
        case types.FACEBOOK_SIGN_IN_START:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            };
        case types.LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                currentUser: null,
            }
        case types.SET_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                currentUser: action.payload,
            }
        case types.REGISTER_SUCCESS:
        case types.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
        case types.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS:
        case types.FACEBOOK_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                currentUser: action.payload,
            };
        case types.REGISTER_FAIL:
        case types.LOGIN_FAIL:
        case types.LOGOUT_FAIL:
        case types.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_FAIL:
        case types.FACEBOOK_SIGN_IN_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload,
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default userReducer;
```

rootReducer.js:

```
import userReducer from "./reducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    user: userReducer
})

export default rootReducer;
```

store.js:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';

const middleware = [thunk];
const logger = createLogger({});

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    middleware.push(logger)
}
export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middleware));
```

login.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { fbSignInInitiate, googleSignInInitiate, loginInitiate } from '../../userauth/actions';

import './login.css';

const Login = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const { email, password } = state;

  const { currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(currentUser || loading) {
      navigate("/dashboard");
    }
  }, [currentUser, navigate]);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleGoogleSignIn = () => {
    dispatch(googleSignInInitiate());
    setLoading(true);

  };
  const handleFBSignIn = () => {
    dispatch(fbSignInInitiate());
    setLoading(true);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!email || !password) {
      return;
    }
    dispatch(loginInitiate(email, password));
    setState({ email: "", password: "" });
    setLoading(true);
  };
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    setState({...state, [name]: value });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div id="logreg-form">
        <form className='form-signin' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h1>
            Sign in
          </h1>
          <div className="social-login">
            <button 
              className='btn google-btn social-btn'
              type='button'
              onClick={handleGoogleSignIn}>
              <span>
                <i className='fab fa-google-plus-g'>Sign in with Google</i>
              </span>
            </button>
            <button 
              className='btn facebook-btn social-btn'
              type='button'
              onClick={handleFBSignIn}>
              <span>
                <i className='fab fa-facebook-f'>Sign in with Facebook</i>
              </span>
              </button>
          </div> 
          <p>OR</p>
          <input
          type="email"
          id="inputEmail"
          className='form-control'
          placeholder='Email Address'
          name="email"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={email}
          required
          />
          <input
          type="password"
          id="inputPassword"
          className='form-control'
          placeholder='Password'
          name="password"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={password}
          required
          />
          <button 
          className='btn btn-secondary btn-block' 
          type="submit">
            <i className="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>Sign In
          </button>
          <hr />
          <p>Don't have an account</p>
          <Link to="/signup">
            <button 
            className='btn btn-primary btn-block' 
            type="button" id="btn-signup">
              <i className='fas fa-user-plus'></i>Sign up New Account
            </button>
          </Link>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>  
  )
}

export default Login;
```

Dashboard.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { logoutInitiate } from '../../userauth/actions';

const Dashboard = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleAuth = () => {
    if(currentUser) {
      dispatch(logoutInitiate());
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>User Dashboard</h1>
        <br />
        <button className='btn btn-danger' onClick={handleAuth}>Logout</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

protectedRoute.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import LoadingToRedirect from './LoadingToRedirect';

const ProtectedRoute = ({children}) => {
  const { currentUser } = useSelector((state) => ({...state.user}));
  return currentUser ? children : <LoadingToRedirect />;
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

App.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Landing, Login, Signup, Contact, Dashboard, Error } from './pages';
import ProtectedRoute from './components/ProtectedRoute';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { auth } from "./Firebase";
import { setUser } from './userauth/actions';

import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      if(authUser) {
        dispatch(setUser(authUser));
      } else {
        dispatch(setUser(null));
      }
    })
  }, [dispatch]);
  

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className='App'>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Landing/>} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup/>} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact/>} />
          <Route
            path="/dashboard"
            element={
              <ProtectedRoute>
                <Dashboard />
              </ProtectedRoute>
            }
          />
          <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "firebase login"? Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73009076/reactjs-authenticated-navigation Is the firebase login the `handleFBSignIn` callback and `fbSignInInitiate` action? Can you provide a [mcve] for all relevant code you are working with?

Comment: Hello, yes sorry my question was confusing, I edited my question and the last part is the action I am taking for facebook authorization using firebase.

Comment: So is it specifically ***only*** the `fbSignInInitiate` action and `auth.signInWithPopup(facebookAuthProvider.addScope("user_birthday, email"))` that doesn't update the `currentUser ` state correctly to effect a navigation action? Can you edit to share the actions and reducer function code?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help. It's more like it does update the currentUser correctly, it just has some time delay for firebase to update the user auth status after the signin popup closes so the page refreshes back to login instead of dashboard. I can manually refresh after that and be redirected to dashboard correctly. I want to add a boolean in Login.js to wait before refreshing but not sure how to do that. I want to initialize loading = setState(false) and then change it to true after login so page refreshes after both user auth and loading is set to true but not sure how to do so.

Comment: What is the authentication source of truth, firebase or your local redux state? Seems you should settle on one or the other and be consistent. From what I can see all your login/register success actions update the same `currentUser` state, which is the single state that triggers a navigation action to `"/dashboard"`. It's not clear where this delay would even come from after a successful login.

Comment: I don't know if my comment got deleted or not but thank you for trying to help me!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes across the same situation, I was able to solve this problem on my own and it's a simple fix. The problem was that the user authorization status wasn't updated whenever I called on Protected Routes but instead it just used the initial state when App.js was called. To get the user authorization status, I saved the user auth in my localStorage. Then, whenever I called user auth status in my redirects, I just fetched from my local storage.